# How can I access ssh of Raspberry PI 4 using static IP assigned to SIM7600E 4G HAT?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

How can I access SSH on RPI using static IP assigned to sim card. I use script to connect RPI with 4g modem (SIM7600E 4G HAT). After script execution I can access internet from RPI, can ping google and also I can ping this static IP successfully from another network, but I can't connect via ssh to my RPI using this static IP. Also I can connect via SSH when I plug in LAN cable and use my WAN IP. Currently I am using this script to connect my RPI with 4g modem:

```
LOG_PATH="/home/ubuntu/logs/lte_startup.log"

echo "---------------------------------" > "$LOG_PATH"
echo "Connecting 4G-LTE" >> "$LOG_PATH"
echo "$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")" >> "$LOG_PATH"

echo "STEP --dms-set-operating-mode='online'" >> "$LOG_PATH"
echo sudo -S qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-set-operating-mode='online' >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 1
echo "STEP --dms-get-operating-mode" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-get-operating-mode >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 1
echo "STEP --nas-get-signal-strength" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-signal-strength >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 2
echo "STEP --nas-get-home-network" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --nas-get-home-network >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 2
echo "STEP sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -w" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -w >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 1
echo "STEP wwan0 down" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo ip link set wwan0 down >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 1
echo "STEP sudo tee /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip" >> "$LOG_PATH"
echo 'Y' | sudo tee /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 1
echo "STEP wwan0 up" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo ip link set wwan0 up >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 1
echo "STEP --wds-start-network" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo qmicli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net='net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header' --wds-start-network="apn='internet',ip-type=4" --client-no-release-cid >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 2
echo "STEP sudo udhcpc -i wwan0" >> "$LOG_PATH"
sudo udhcpc -i wwan0 >> "$LOG_PATH"
sleep 2
echo "STEP sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start" >> "$LOG_PATH"

sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start >> "$LOG_PATH"
```

There were few times when I could connect to RPI using 4g modem and what I noticed was that when dhcp client (udhcpc) assign the exact same IP address to wwan0 interface as I got from my provider then I can connect via SSH to RPI. But I don't know if it was the case and ip from udhcpc always changes. Can I somehow configure this process so that I can access ssh of RPI using static ip from sim card?